# In sharepoint 2010, Using client object model ,The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-foundation, csom

```
try
{
    web = context.Web;
    List list = context.Web.Lists.GetByTitle(listName);
    CamlQuery query = new CamlQuery();
    if (sprootpath == null)
    {
        query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/" + listName + "/";
    }
    else
    {
        query.FolderServerRelativeUrl = "/" + sprootpath + "/";
    }
    var listItems = list.GetItems(query);
    context.Load(listItems);
    context.ExecuteQuery();

}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Debug.Write(ex);    
    return false;
}
```

1. I tried
   `ClientContext context = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, 800, 600);` which generated an auto pop up for login. Then after that the context object is passed to the method above.
2. I tried `clientCtx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain")`
3. Checked SharePoint app pools, claim service in central admin & IIS admin services in Windows services are in running state.  - Running

Comment: Make sure you have provided credentials

Comment: I used  ClientContext context = ClaimClientContext.GetAuthenticatedContext(siteUrl, 800, 600); method which generate auto pop up for login. Then after that context  object passed to above mention method.

Comment: Try clientCtx.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("username", "password", "domain"); 
& Check here also get error or not

Comment: yes i try that. But same error 500 Internal server

Comment: Check your SharePoint app pools, claim service in central admin & iis admin services in Windows services are in running state.

Comment: " Claims to Windows Token Service " is running.

Comment: And what about app pools & iis admin services?

Comment: pools & iis admin services are running

Comment: @M.Qassas , Now its clear ?

Comment: @M.Qassas , if its clear to understand then request to remove from hold.

Comment: can you explain a bit more?, it's a different site collection? it's a fba site? What uri are you using to get the context?

Answer (score 0):

This is salesforce example but very useful and help

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000221207&type=1